# react add setTimeout to loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I am using react to fetch data and show it in my app . If I am loading , I display the message : "Loading ..." .

What I want is to use `setTimeout()` to show the loading message for a few more seconds than it should be . However I do not know how to write this in react .

My code :

```
export default function JobList() {
  
  const {loading ,error , jobs} = useFetch();
  

  return (
    <div>
      {loading && <p> Loading  </p>} //HOW DO I USE SETTIMEOUT ON THIS <P> ELEMENT ? 
      {jobs && jobs.map(j=>return <p> {j.title} </p>)}
    </div>  
  );
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default function JobList() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const {loading ,error , jobs} = useFetch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) {
      setIsLoading(true)
    }

    if (!loading) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsLoading(false)
      }, 2000)
    }
  }, [loading])

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading && <p> Loading  </p>}
      {!isLoading && jobs?.map(j=>return <p> {j.title} </p>)}
    </div>  
  );
}
```

Create a state called isLoading with useState hook. Use that to conditionally render the Loading component/spinner.

`setIsLoading` is called in `useEffect` everytime `loading` changes. So, if you add the `setTimeout` in useEffect it will change from true to false after 2000 milliseconds.

This assumes loading from useFetch is a boolean.

Also, you can use optional chaining in the jobs.map render if you are using ES2020. You can avoid writing an additional check.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution you should try something like this.

```
export default function JobList() {
  
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const request = useFetch('https://example.com')

  request.post('/todos', {
    any: 'data'
  }).then(response => {
      settimeout(() => {
          setLoading(false)
      }, 1000 ) // here you can set delay
  }).catch(error => {
      // error handing here...
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {loading && <p> Loading  </p>} //HOW DO I USE SETTIMEOUT ON THIS <P> ELEMENT ? 
      {jobs && jobs.map(j=>return <p> {j.title} </p>)}
    </div>  
  );
  
}
```